# Android dateformat display format invalid

Tags: android

This might be easy, and I might no see the obvious, but I'm like 1 hour trying to figure out how to convert the date from string to a format I want.

```
String date_begin = "15-10-2013 10:25:31";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // This is the format I want
Date startDate;
try {
    startDate = df.parse(date_begin);
    String startDateString1 = df.format(startDate);
    Log.e("New date: ", startDateString1);      
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the output is the following:

> New date:(2799): 0021-04-04 10:25:31

How d'hell is displaying this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`15-10-2013 10:25:31` is not in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format. Parse it with `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` instead.

Looks like you want to change the formatting. The solution is to use two `SimpleDateFormat`s, one for parsing and another for formatting the output. Like this:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
startDate = inputFormat.parse(date_begin);
String startDateString1 = outputFormat.format(startDate);
Log.e("New date: ", startDateString1);
```

Comment: I don't get it. I want it to display yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss not dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.

Comment: @user2742861 Parsing a string to `Date` is one thing, formatting a `Date` to a `String` is another. You can use separate `SimpleDateFormat`s for each. Updated the answer.

Comment: still don't get it. Are you telling me that I need to create  two SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 2):

you have to parse the date with a different format

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the date_begin , SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") is not same . Both should be in same format.